# HTML5 Dynamic Video Background

Tags: jquery, html, video, event-handling, append

here is my code

```js
$("body").prepend("<div class='fullscreen-bg'><video loop muted autoplay class='fullscreen-bg__video' ><source src='https://www.iresearchservices.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/bgvideo.mp4' type='video/mp4'></video></div>")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and its working fine. but what i need is, I want to call a function say remove-pre-loader(), once the video is loaded.

i have a per-loader screen, i want to remove the pre-loader once the video is loaded.

Comment: can you create fiddle? or you can use video.addEventListener("canplaythrough", function() { event

Comment: what do you mean by video loaded? whether it's completely downloaded by the browser?

Comment: @AravindS, the problem is when all dom elements are loaded, the page displays without the video and after some time when the video is loaded by browser then the video is also displayed.

Comment: can you try `preload="none"` and see how it works

Comment: but when to use preload='none', i need a way to find out video is loaded. then only i can hide the preloader.

Comment: here is fiddle for it
https://jsfiddle.net/kaleem78/xpvt214o/466058/

Comment: can you check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Aravi/s17a5vkg/

Comment: thank you so much. your code works. i just changed the loadstart to canplaythrough as suggested by @BhumiShah. that solved my problem. 
thank you once again :-)

Comment: Happy to know that ...i edited my answer to include `canplaythrough` also...if it helped, accept it ..Thanks

Comment: @KaleemNalband: let me add as answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `loadeddata` or `canplaythrough` event to check whether the browser has loaded the current frame of the audio/video. See a full list of possible video events [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp)

```js
$("body").prepend(
  "<div class='fullscreen-bg'><video loop muted autoplay class='fullscreen-bg__video' ><source src='https://www.iresearchservices.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/bgvideo.mp4' type='video/mp4'><source src='https://www.iresearchservices.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/bgvideo.mp4' type='video/mp4'><source src='https://www.iresearchservices.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/bgvideo.mp4' type='video/mp4'></video></div>"
);
$(".fullscreen-bg__video").on("loadeddata", function () {
        alert("Video Loaded")
    });
```

```css
.fullscreen-bg {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -100;
}

.fullscreen-bg__video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .fullscreen-bg__video {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .fullscreen-bg__video {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .fullscreen-bg__video {
    height: 300%;
    top: -100%;
  }
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .fullscreen-bg__video {
    width: 300%;
    left: -100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @KaleemNalband if this answer helped you? then accept and upvote it..thanks